# PHP MVC Send object variable with href

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

Building a school management system using only PHP and PDO - college project.

Now I'm using MVC, and I'm having trouble sending information from one view to another.

This is the View I want information from

```
<?php
    include_once 'model/student.php';
    include_once 'model/courses.php';

        $selected = new Student();
        $students = Student::getAllStudents();
        $selected2 = new Course();
        $courses = Course::getAllCourses();

?>
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <span style="font-size: 24px;"> <u>Students</u> - <button style="color:black;width: 30px;height: 35px;"><a href="?controller=pages&action=logout">+</a></button></span>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <?php /* this is where I have the problem, the href attribute - I'm not sure I am sending the information correctly */
            foreach($students as $stu){
                ?> <div> Student Name: <a href='? controller=student&action=showstudent&student_id=<?php echo $stu->id ?>'> <?php echo $stu->name ?> </a></div><br> 

                <div> Student Phone: <?php echo $stu->phone ?> </div><br> <hr> <?php
            }
        ?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <span style="font-size: 24px;"> <u>Courses</u> - <button style="color:black;width: 30px;height: 35px;"><a href="?controller=pages&action=logout">+</a></button></span>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <?php 
            foreach($courses as $cur){
                echo "<span><a href='#' ><b><u><i>" .$cur->name . "</i></u></b></a></span></br><hr>";

            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the Controller and Model

```
<?php

class StudentController {
    public $student_model;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->student_model= new Student();
    }

    public function showstudent($id) {
        $find = $this->student_model->findStudentById($id);
        if($find==TRUE){
            require_once 'views/pages/container/student_into_container.php';
        }
        else{
            echo "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';
class Student{

    public $name;
    public $phone;
    public $email;
    public $img;
    public $id;

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public static function getAllStudents(){
        $students = [];
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $req = $db->query('SELECT id, name, phone, email, image FROM students');
        $students_info = $req->fetchAll();
        foreach ($students_info as $student_info){
              $stu = new Student;
              $stu->id = $student_info['id'];
              $stu->name = $student_info['name'];
              $stu->phone = $student_info['phone'];
              $stu->email = $student_info['email'];
              $stu->img = $student_info['image'];
              array_push($students, $stu);
          }
          return $students;
    }

    public function findStudentById($id){

        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = :id');
        $req->execute(array('id' => $id));
        $student = $req->fetch();

        return $student;
    }
}
```

And this is the view I want to get the $id from a student I found
and show all his value fields - this is the student_into_container.php from the StudentController page

```
<?php 

       require_once 'connection.php'
?>
<div style="" class="">  
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <?php 
        require_once 'views/pages/container/student_courses_aside.php';

    ?>
    </div>
    <div style="color: black;" class="col-lg-8 blackboard ">
        <div class="blackboard-container" style="margin-top:10px;font-size:36px;">
           <?php foreach($students as $stu){
                echo "<span> Student Name: <a href='#'>". $stu->name . "</a></span></br>";
                echo "<span> Student Phone: " . $stu->phone . "</span></br> <hr>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Totally lost here, any help would help.
In short?
Show in once view an information sent from another view with an href attribute

Comment: first can you remove the ? before the controller Student Name: <a href='controller=student&action=showstudent&student_id=<?php echo $stu->id ?>'>  second i dont see you using the variable Student_id sent from the view to controller the one you are sending in url the MVC is about sending the information from the view to the controller and the controller do what ever needs to be done with it

Comment: fix that and update us on the result

Comment: Hmm ... not sure, if I should tear apart this code, because it has a lot of issues ... but it wouldn't really count as "answer" :(